# Can this Python code be further shrunk?

Tags: python, coding-style

Below is Python code that fetches all of the sub-domains within a domain. It takes a file as input that contains the page source for a website. The second argument is the domain name. For example: `"https://www.sometime.com"`.

```
import re
def getSubDomains(fil,domain):
   with open(fil) as f:
    subDomainLst = []
    for line in f:
      m = re.findall(r'\bhref="\https://[\w+\.*]+%s/'%domain,line)
      if(m):
         for ele in m: subDomainLst.append(ele.split('/')[2])
      else:
            continue
   subDomainLst = list(set(subDomainLst))
   for ele in subDomainLst: print ele 
def main():
    fil1,domain1 = raw_input("Enter the file name\n"),raw_input("Enter the domain\n")
    getSubDomains(fil1,domain1)
main() if __name__ == '__main__' else Pass
```

I've tried shrinking the inner 'if else statement' to

```
for ele in m: subDomainLst.append(ele.split('/')[2]) if(m) else continue
```

But this gives an error.

Can the above code be shrunk further (16 lines for now) so that it takes up minimum number of lines and become more pythonic?

Comment: You could remove the `else: continue` part completely, as it is not needed in the first place.

Comment: Note that *"so that it takes up minimum number of lines and become more pythonic?"* can be mutually exclusive - Python prioritises **readability** of code, and it's bad form to compress for the sake of it (missing out whitespace, single-character identifiers, etc.) Read [the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and explain **why** you want it to be shorter.

Comment: @Frederic
Your suggestion is descent however I've figured out something.
 One can use the upper case as 'Continue' instead of 'continue'. So the final line used as will be

      for ele in m: subDomainLst.append(ele.split('/')[2]) if(m) else Continue

Comment: @jonrsharpe I welcome your suggestion. Here I'm trying to give this program as a challenge/ competetion to my fellow mates for coding the shortest code. So mine has to be the shortest.

Comment: @Harvey what's the point in competing over length? Why don't you change the challenge, to write the *neatest* code or *most efficient* code? One point of competition is to hone your skills, and in this case you seem to be honing the wrong ones.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
I completely agree and will be utilizing up your valuable suggestion however here the idea is to convey the power of Python and its varied functionality. Most of my mates are Java programmers. Just for fun you know. I myself try to write clean code. The same style guide, I use for reference.

Comment: Some notes: (1) you do not need to initialize the list since the list comprehension already does it, (2) the Pass keyword is lowercase

Comment: @Daniele 
Have edited your (1) suggestion however in (2), if I use 'pass', gives an error while 'Pass' doesn't.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass . Also you do not need to subDomainLst = list(set(subDomainLst))

Comment: I have editd my answer below with the full snippet

Comment: Don't put answers in the question. Also, I hope you'll be telling your mates you didn't actually write it, and forfeiting the challenge...

Comment: @johnrsharpe    The challenge was put up and many tried hard optimizing their code (Java, .NET etc)
I also allowed coders to take help from Stack Overflow/ exchange. Me was obviously not participating and kept the above code as the benchmark.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add *continue*. You can try doing like this, even though I DO NOT recommend as it makes the code unreadable.

```
subDomainLst = [ele.split('/')[2] for line in f for ele in re.findall(r'\bhref="\https://[\w+\.*]+%s/' % domain, line)]
```

Btw you should indent your code by 4 spaces and try to avoid one-line uncomprehensible statements: pythonic means also readable

Complete code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import re 
    fil, domain = raw_input("Enter the file name\n"), raw_input("Enter the domain\n")
    with open(fil) as f:
        print '\n'.join([ele.split('/')[2] for line in f for ele in re.findall(r'\bhref="\https://[\w+\.*]+%s/' % domain, line)])
```

Comment: Got your point. 
This will be kept as a challenge for the shortest line code.

Comment: I made it on a single line, since the "goal" is to make it short.

Comment: Cheers. You're a gem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the `if` statement into `try..except`

```
try:
    for ele in m: subDomainLst.append(ele.split('/')[2])
except TypeError:
    print "OMG m is not iterable!"
```

Or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You have two different goals: shrink the lines and become more pythonic.
Here it is in one line, but it is not pythonic:

```
import re;fil,domain = raw_input("Enter the file name\n"),raw_input("Enter the domain\n");print '\n'.join(set(ele.split('/')[2] for line in open(fil) for ele in (re.findall(r'\bhref="\https://[\w+\.*]+%s/'%domain,line) or ())))
```

Comment: Anything other than ';' will be appreciated.